# Mocking MailController with ActionMailer.net using Moq 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing, moq

I'm new to Moq, so any help would be great. I keep getting a null reference error in my code when I'm trying to set up a test. Here is the line of code where I'm getting the error below.

```
_iMailController.RequesterEmail(model).Deliver();
```

Here is what my test looks like:

```
 _mockMailController = new Mock<IMailController>();

 mockMailController .Setup(x => x.RequesterEmail(new Model())).Returns(**new EmailResult()**);
```

The bold part is where I'm stuck at. It takes 7 parameters and dont know what to put to fake out the EmailResult.

Comment: There's example code at https://github.com/jgeurts/MvcKickstart/blob/master/KickstartTemplate/KickstartTemplate.Tests/Controllers/Account/ControllerTestBase.cs - I haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing, The Return part will single return values like string, list, bool or Int ect.

So you can easily pass the value which you get in return on the **RequesterEmail** on the **IMailController**. So you have to check the which value get retun from the **RequesterEmail** method.

You may also use the below code as example:

```
mockMailController .Setup(x => x.RequesterEmail(It.IsAny<Model>())).Returns(**new EmailResult()**);
```

Refet the below Part too.

It mentioned about how many parameter you passed in the **RequesterEmail** method. If there is 7 parameters passed on the method then you may have to pass 7 parmeter like bleow

Please look deeply in parameter and return on both codes down here.
And look where i use ModelClass in both below codes.

If the Method have parameters like below:

```
public void RequesterEmail( string, int, list, EmailClass, someClass, bool, string);
{
return  ModelClass;
}
```

then you may have to write the code as below

```
mockMailController .Setup(x => x.RequesterEmail(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>(), 
It.IsAny<EmailClass>(), It.IsAny<someClass>(), It.IsAny<bool>(), 
It.IsAny<string>())).Return(ModelClass)
```